# Missing magnifying glass icon in Conga Composer template list

Tags: lightning-experience, conga-composer

I'm using Conga Composer on lightning, but unable to figure out which setting allows the user to see the magnifying glass icon. This is the button that links to the Conga Template edit page.

The user was recently given permissions to modify and edit templates and is able to do so by navigating to the Conga Templates, but is for come reason not able to see the shortcut button.

Is there a switch that controls this?

Comment: You'll have to check with Conga support.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.